# Merging layers after iteration in QGIS Modeler

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have two models that I apply one after the other:

- The first one works in iteration mode, creating after itself a large number of output layers (the model cannot work outside the iteration mode),
- the second model collects the layers obtained in the first model together.

The problem is that the process of merging layers is performed within the framework of the first model without using the second one. I know that there are post-processing possibilities, but I have not found a solution. Perhaps someone has already met with a similar question and found an answer to it, or someone can take up the solution of this problem for me. Rebuilding models without iteration will not work. For example, I give two simple models for better understanding.

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : model1
Group : 
With QGIS : 32003
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class (QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('input', 'input', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output', 'output', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': 1,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0, 
            'INPUT': parameters['input'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0, 
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output']
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output'] = outputs['']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model1'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model1'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return ()
```

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : model2
Group : 
With QGIS : 32003
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class (QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers('Input2', 'Input_2', layerType=QgsProcessing.TypeMapLayer, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output_2', 'output_2', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        alg_params = {
            'CRS': None,
            'LAYERS': parameters['Input2'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output_2']
        }
        outputs[''] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output_2'] = outputs['']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'model2'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'model2'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return ()
```

Comment: I usually create a python script to merge all the outputs and execute manually. For example a mode l ouputs many layers named zs.     `layerlist = [layer for layer in QgsProject().instance().mapLayers().values() if "zs" in layer.name().lower()]` then

`processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':layerlist,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})`

Comment: Well, I honestly tried, but my knowledge of Python, tending to zero, was not enough to solve such an apparently simple task. Please help me with this @BERA

Comment: @BERA, Thank you, but this turned out to be a bit not what I needed. I need this function to work within the framework of the algorithm itself, connecting all the output layers into one and displaying only it as a result. I've tried using the post-processing features, but apparently they can't be used the way I want.

Answer (score 2):

This model have two input parameters:

1. A Vector Feature with four polygons in it
2. A vector layer.

The model with clip the second parameter four times, once for each input feature and output four temp layers named `clip_output`

[image]

After the model, this code will list the outputs using their output names (they are the only layers in the map with `output` in the name, and execute merge vector layers:

```
all_outputs = [] #Create an empty list

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For all layers in the Qgis Project
    if "output" in layer.name(): #Find the ones with output in the layer name
        all_outputs.append(layer) #And append them to the list
        
#Merge the outputs using all_outputs list as input
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
    {'LAYERS':all_outputs,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]